# Key constraints/indexes/etc... confusion on my part

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, unique-constraint

I have two tables, each carry a column labelled "CN" which is a GUID value generated by my application. The first table holds user data, the second table holds logon data (in this case, salt values). each user should get 2 rows exactly - one with a salt for logon and one with a salt for security questions/answers. this leaves me with what I believe is the inability to accurately control how data goes into the table... i want some kind of uniqueness but given the data in the table I don't think I can.. for example:

User A has a CN of 4b51b0d6-5168-4cca-a35d-00cca2b10423 - this value is stored in the user table as a primary key. User A can have two distinct salt values, one for login and one for reset. That leaves two rows with the same CN, but different reset types and different salts. However, there will be multiple rows of logon salt and reset salt - one each per user, so I cant PK off the salt type, only the salt value I think... if I'm thinking wrong please let me know. If you need more info I can certainly share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a compound primary key in the second table.

```
CREATE TABLE salts (
  CN CHAR(36) NOT NULL
  salt_type ENUM('logon', 'reset') NOT NULL,
  salt VARCHAR(...),
  PRIMARY KEY (CN, salt_type)
);
```

This will allow one row for each *pair* of a given CN value, and the salt type, which may have one of two values.